# Weblogic: JAX-WS request results in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get Request or Response when the current state is completed or dispatched

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, jax-ws

```
<23.8.2019 23:28:07,649 CEST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[[HTTP:101402]Cannot get Request or Response when the current state is completed or dispatched.] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [HTTP:101402]Cannot get Request or Response when the current state is completed or dispatched.
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncContextImpl.getRequest(AsyncContextImpl.java:233)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSAsyncListener$1.onComplete(WSAsyncListener.java:69)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncEventsManager$OnCompleteHandler.handle(AsyncEventsManager.java:223)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncEventsManager$1.run(AsyncEventsManager.java:140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.async.AsyncEventsManager$1.run(AsyncEventsManager.java:134)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I have a Spring Boot WAR application having jax-ws webservice (spring enabled with org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring:jaxws-spring:1.9).

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Using a servlet: `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet` with mapping: `"/ws/*"`.

Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new WSSpringServlet(), "/ws/*");
    }
// other code with working SpringBinding
}
```

WebService:

```
@MTOM
@Component
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.model.SomeWS")
public class SomeWSImpl implements SomeWS {

    private SomeService service;

    @Override
    public SomeResponse someOperation(SomeRequest request) throws SomeWSFault {
        return new SomeResponse("Dummy content");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setService(SomeService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

On each request the console logs an error but the request is dispatched successfully and that results in SPAM in logs.

Some related post about the issue:
https://github.com/javaee/metro/issues/47

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Using a weblogic 12.2.1.3.0

Comment: found any solution ?